# What word can I use for an introduction to a fiction book?

Tags: introduction

I want to talk about a fiction book I'm working on but can't find what to call the intro. A 'foreword' is generally written by someone other than the author, and I read that an 'introduction' is used for non-fiction books. I heard about a 'preface', but I'm not sure if that's what I should use. What word can I use for an introduction to a fiction book?

Comment: Introduction is used frequently when a scholar writes introductory material for a classic. But there should be no reason to write an introduction for a new work. It should stand alone.

Comment: what are you introducing? What content would go in this section?

Comment: The story may be sort of confusing, so I want to talk a bit about it to help people understand it better.

Comment: *Preface*, I think.  Here's a source: http://www.bpsbooks.com/BPS-Books-blog/bid/21727/What-s-the-Difference-Between-a-Foreword-Preface-and-Introduction. // OR: let's say the thing that might be confusing is, for example, the setting.  You could title that first part "A Note about the Setting."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two words which come to mind for me are:

- Prologue (or prolog) - *would work especially well if writing an epilogue*
- Prelude

Another word which *might* be used is preamble, but I don't think that would work as well.

**EDIT:**

Conversely to annotating the introduction, you could always put it at the beginning *and not call it anything*. If the chapters are annotated in some way, either by number or name, leaving your introduction separate without a name will distinguish it from the book itself.

Comment: *Prologue* is absolutely the right word if the beginning material is part of the story, but *not* if it is outside the novel's reality.  I've only ever heard *prelude* used in a musical context --it doesn't suggest the desired meaning to me.

Comment: Tom Robbins does this pretty frequently, just making his first chapter a reflection on the upcoming story. _Jitterbug Perfume_ gives this chapter its own name, "Today's Special," in _Still Life with Woodpecker_ it's "Prologue," in _Skinny Legs and All_ it's "Prelude."

Comment: For what I'm working on, 'backstory' may work as well, although it's not as commonly used and may be a bit confusing.